# TypeError: Undefined is not an object error in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am fairly new to react native and I am trying to render json data on the android emulator, however, I am getting an error which I have no idea about. Will appreciate any help I can get.

[LibraryList.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wNdx.png)

[ListItems.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab8gg.png)

[The json data trying to be rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJsPT.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlDea.png)

[The error shown on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJGkH.png)

Comment: the json data where do you keep that.

Comment: Make a const for the json data and export it from that file and then import it in the file where you want to use.

Comment: hey @knevagi, it would be really easy to help you if you can share your code on the https://snack.expo.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you replace your class code in LibraryList.js with this?

```
class LibraryList extends Component {
    renderRow(library) {
        return <ListItems library={library} />;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.libraries}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
                keyExtractor={item => item.title}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man that worked. Thank you so much. Can you please explain what you did?

Comment: ListView is no longer used. You should use FlatList instead.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist